# What error will i get if i use the same ID for multiple HTML elements?

Tags: html, css

I understand that unlike class, an ID should be unique in a HTML document. What will happen if I use the same id multiple times for multiple HTML elements? Will it throw any error? or will it just not work?

I tried to try this scenario but wanted to know more context around it.

Comment: Official documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. I think it worked and my confusion was as I was thinking about it only from the CSS and HTML context. But now as I understand this will cause issues in JS context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be invalid HTML.

In some environments, it may produce a console warning that multiple IDs in a single document is invalid. Harmless, but annoying.

It will prevent `document.getElementById` from working properly for those elements, because `getElementById` selects by ID, but there should only be one element with a given ID in the document. Similarly, it may prevent `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` with ID selectors from working properly.

Using the same ID multiple times may well not break your application in most cases, but just because it might be doable in some circumstances doesn't mean it's a good idea. There's no reason to do it, so don't.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Unlike html class, We cannot apply same id in multiple html elements, It will not throw any error but only the first element with the id will work and other elements won't work.

```js
$('#foo').on('click',function(){
  alert('work')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">Click me</div>
```

```js
$('#foo').on('click',function(){
  alert(' work')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">Click me(work)</div>
<div id="foo">Click me(won't work)</div>
<div id="foo">Click me(won't work)</div>
```

Comment: you should give some explanation, Here the first Id is giving output but in some cases this will also made the program to break :(

Comment: Yes, But what i am trying to say is, we cannot use same id for multiple html elements

Comment: definitely. For such use cases we have  classes instead of id's

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it and it works if we put same id name for multiple elements its going to change properties where the id is same

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really happens. JavaScript and CSS selectors will only select the first element they find with the id. It's not like your website will crash. It's just very bad practice because an id should be unique on each page.